# Dagster running pipelines with multiple projects

Tags: python, docker, devops, etl, dagster

I need a bit of help for the deployment in AWS using dagster projects, unfortunately couldn't found in the offical documentation.

So a bit of context with the simple solids and pipelines using repo.py is working perfectly file. But the problem starts to occur in aws when I change the structure of solid and pipelines in a [new directory project](https://docs.dagster.io/getting-started/create-new-project). So the objective is not to use repo.py for the trigger of pipelines (here is the [example](https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/guides/docker) which shows I am refereeing too ). This line 65 of docker-compose.yaml file uses this command

`dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -f repo.py`

and the same command goes to our AWS infrastructure for the trigger of pipelines. Instead what I am looking for is to utilise the workspace.yaml file (where i can add multiple python packages ).

So does anyone think can be command be used like this ?  (presently there is no existing '-w' parameter with dagster api )

`dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -w workspace.yaml`

If not then another Idea is to use Module instead of 'repo.py' in the main directory. Dagit works really well with the module

`dagit -m project-01`

but can this be possible with the dagster ? so the command would become like this  `dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -m project-01` (presently it throws an error that project-01 don't exists )